# Representation of quotient of Lie group by finite central subgroup

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a real Lie group with a faithful continuous representation on a finite dimensional vector space $V$.
Let $C$ be a finite and central subgroup of $G$.

How can I obtain a faithful representation of $G/C$?

Comment: What do you mean by vector subspace representation of $C$? A $C$-stable subspace of $V$? Why this should exist?

Comment: @DavidHill : this could very well not be faithful, in fact $V_0$ can be $0$ (take $G=$ any subgroup of $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ containing $-I_n$, have it act on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and put $C=\{-I_n, I_n\}$ for instance)

Comment: @FlybyNight : no, the restriction gives a representation of $C$ on $V$

Comment: @FlybyNight $\rho$ is a morphism $C\to GL(V)$, so no.

Comment: @FlybyNight a representation of a group $G$ on a space $V$ is a linear action of $G$ on $V$, that is, either a map $G\times V\to V$ such that for all $g$, $v\mapsto gv$ is linear, satisfying a few axioms , or equivalently a morphism $G\to GL(V)$

Comment: @WrabbitW : I think you have to clarify what you mean by "obtain". For instance $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ clearly acts faithfully on $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $PSL(2,\mathbb{R}) = SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\{-I_n, I_n\}$ has no faithful representation of dimension $1$ or $2$, so you can't "obtain" one by taking a subspace or a quotient space.

Comment: @FlybyNight there is, but as $\rho(g), \rho(h)$ aren't vectors of $V$, this doesn't form a subspace of $V$

Comment: I know the result to be true over $\mathbb{C}$ (Cf Hochshild The structure of Lie Group XVII 3.1) but this strongly uses Schur's Lemma. I hope this is true for the reals but the construction might be more difficult. For example if I take $G=SL2(\mathbb{R}$ and $C=Z(G)$ I can get a faithful representation of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ if I act on its Lie algebra.

Comment: Is your representation irreducible?

Comment: @Max see my previous comment, $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is centerless hence the adjoint representation is faithful.

Comment: @WrabbitW ok so you take "obtain" to be a bit more wide-ended than just "subspaces or quotient spaces"

Comment: @DavidHill : even then, I'm not sure $V_0$ is faithful as a $G/C$ representation; how would you prove that ?

Comment: @DavidHill I feel that the hypothesis $V_0 \neq 0$ would work for a solvable complex Lie group (Lie-Kolchin) but would not hold in general.

Comment: @max nope, you are right. restricting kills the argument I had in mind.

Comment: @WrabbitW : just a question though, in your $SL(2)$ example, you did not start from a representation of $SL(2)$ to get one of $PSL(2)$, you built one "out of thin air": how does that relate to your question ? (that is, I still think you should be clearer on what "obtain" means)

Comment: @Max Ok I see what you mean. It is true that the adjoint representation has nothing to do with the standard $SL_2$ representation. I think I was unclear with the term "obtain" precisely because I don't really need the representation to be obtained from the one I had I just need to be sure that the quotient is representable. I am not sur if that helps understanding my question?